# Using nohup in Ubuntu - how to make it not show the job number?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nohup

I'm running this command:

```
$ nohup command > foo.out 2> foo.err < /dev/null &
```

My problem is that even though `nohup` makes my command run in the background, it prints out something like this to my terminal:

```
[1] 27918
```

How do I make it not output the job number? I just want it to do it in the background without telling me anything. On Mac OS X, that's exactly what happens, so I'm a little annoyed that it works differently on Ubuntu...

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The [1] 27918 is coming from the & not the nohup

Comment: Thanks Matt, that did it. Now how do I close this question...

Comment: The way to do that is mark an answer as accepted using the checkmark next to it.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/faq section "How do I ask questions"

Answer (score 4):

Job information is displayed by your shell, not `nohup`.

You could try this alternative:

```
(yourcommand&)
```

`(` spawns a subshell, which handles job control differently.

(I have `nh() { ("$@" &); }` in my ~/.bashrc, so I can type `nh command` to do the same thing.)

Another, different way:

```
setsid yourcommand
```

*Edit:* It seems that `(setsid yourcommand &)` is the best combination, since it detaches from the tty *and* works equally in interactive and script modes.

Comment: (command &) worked for me where I was having ioctl error with nohup.

Answer (score 1):

The [1] 27918 is coming from the & not the nohup.

Put the command you want to run in the background inside a script file:

```
#!/bin/sh
/path/to/command & >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

and then call that with nohup

```
nohup sh /path/to/my/script > foo.out 2> foo.err < /dev/null
```

The output of & is then redirected to /dev/null inside the script.

Comment: `&` is only a command terminator, it doesn't output anything and you cannot redirect it. In interactive mode, the job line is printed by the shell; in non-interactive (including scripts), it remains quiet. Your inner redirects apply to output of the command itself, and I do not think the outer redirects will override them.

Answer (score 1):

Just as the one above mentioned (Thanks, by the way).

Within a script named test.ksh:

```
#!/bin/ksh
./test2.ksh >/dev/null
nohup ksh test2.ksh < /dev/null
echo  "whatever"
```

Where test2.ksh is another script (or may be a command):

```
#!/bin/ksh
max=10
for ((i=2; i<=$max; ++i )) ; do
    echo -e "\n Hello world "
done
```

Then, run:

```
~> ksh test.ksh
```

and the output is:

```
nohup: appending output to `nohup.out'
whatever
~>
```

It worked for me

If you keep the & in the redirection

```
./test2.ksh & >/dev/null
```

It will print both in the tty and the file .out